# How to build a predicate which references an entity from a relationship?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

I need to make a predicate with an Entity with a relation to another entity to a relation with another entity. Is this possible? I have the following entities:

```
Entity: BOOK
Entity: AUTOR
Entity: SCHOOL
```

And these relations:

```
BOOK -> relationAutor <- AUTOR
AUTOR -> relationSchool <- SCHOOL
SCHOOL -> attribute "country"
```

So, I need to filter/fetch some BOOKs, from a specific `country`. Because I have some relation from the entity BOOK to the attribute `country` (from the entity SCHOOL) through the entity AUTOR, I tried to concatenate this predicate:

```
NSString *pred = [[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationAutor.relationSchool.country IN %@",[countries valueForKey:@"country"]]predicateFormat];
predicateFormat = [predicateFormat stringByAppendingFormat:@" AND (%@)",pred];
```

But my code crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (relationAutor.relationSchool.country IN {France})'
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? And if it is, how would I build such a predicate?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine predicates by string concatenation. If you need a predicate that is the "AND" combination of 2 (or more) other predicates, use `NSCompoundPredicate`, e.g.

```
NSArray *countries = @[@"France"]; 
NSPredicate *pred1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationAutor.relationSchool.country IN %@", countries];
NSPredicate *pred2 = ... // other predicate

// pred = pred1 AND pred2:
NSPredicate *pred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[pred1, pred2]];
```

See also the documentation for `predicateFormat`:

> The string returned by this method is not guaranteed to be the same as
>   a string used to create the predicate using predicateWithFormat: etc.
>   You cannot use this method to create a persistent representation of a
>   predicate that you could use to recreate the original predicate.

Comment: Actually, I'm combining another predicates and everything is fine. My other's predicates are simples, just with one relation, but with this predicate, with 2 relations, the code crash

Comment: @user1600801: Does your code crash or the code that I suggested? - I have updated my answer with more information. It is easier to help if you show the complete code how you create and combine the predicates.